# how to make html5 video fit into a banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

am working to add a video in the banner which need to be fit the Full width and Height of the banner. What am doing is follow

Html

```
 <div class="banner">
  <video>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
video {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 566px;
    z-index: -100;

}
.banner{
  width: 100%;
  height: 566px;
  background: red;
  overflow: none;

}
```

Working fiddle : [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ypL0eym8/2/)

But video is not fit into banner

Comment: you dont want to show the red background ??

Comment: yes it needs to be filled with video :)

Comment: do you need the `height` set to `566px` ? If you make it `100%` or `auto`, it should fit. [Check this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ypL0eym8/10/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `object-fit: cover` :

```
video {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 566px;
    z-index: -100;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ypL0eym8/12/)

Comment: but its only working in chrome, rest of the browsers it seems video is broken.

Comment: @JothiKannan - works on my FF. Don't have IE. idk how to fix if doesn't work on IE. xD

Comment: you see its working in FF but video is hidded at bottom it not good same like in chrome

Answer (score 1):

You need to set  width: auto; to it solve your problem

```
video {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: 566px;
    z-index: -100;

}
.banner{
  width: 100%;
  height: 566px;
  background: red;
  overflow: none;

}
```

Js fiddle demo
http://fiddle.jshell.net/ypL0eym8/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
video {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 566px;
    z-index: -100;
    background: cover;
    overflow: none;
}
```

Worked fine change background became "cover".

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ypL0eym8/11/

** EDIT **

Nvm, take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39528132/6266518) answer instead. I was unaware of "object-fit" and it works much better.

Comment: but then the red parts dissapear. Video does not fill up to 566px height